# Giving relative path to java applet param

Tags: applet, relative-path

How can i tell this java applet to take the .jar file from the same folder where the .html file is?

I have tried every possible way i know, and only "http://localhost/blabla/some.jar" or "file:///c:/blabla/some.jar" works in that case, so i need to type the absolute path every time.

Is it possible to make it working with the relative path ?

```
<param name="archive" value="some.jar">
```

Because that doesnt work, the java applet gives an error "file not found" even when the file is in the same folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the codebase attribute in the  tag as the folder "blabla"